# What does $\mathbb{C}-\{(-\infty,0]\}$ look like?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

What does $\mathbb{C}-\{(-\infty,0]\}$ look like?

I'm trying to sketch a graph on $\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is $\mathbb{C}-\{(-\infty,0]\}$, and I can't quite wrap my head around what this looks like.

If I'm looking at it like a 2D plane, would I be leaving out the left half of the plane, or just the negative half of the real axis?

For context, I'm trying to visualize $\log(z)$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: You‘re just leaving out the non-positive part of the real axis.

Comment: By the way, you mean $\Bbb C-(-\infty,0]$, not $\Bbb C-\{(-\infty,0]\}$. A pedantic point, but one that's still probably worth understanding to firm up one's understanding of sets.

Comment: Okay, so it's more like I cut a slit in the plane than removing a whole section of it?

Comment: Yes. Fun fact: That's precisely the German name for such spaces, "geschlitzte (komplexe) Ebene". Though I haven't really heard a corresponding English name. Btw, if you reply in the comments, you should pin via @, otherwise the previous comment authors won't see your reply.

Comment: Think of it as a piece of paper where you've made a straight cut from an edge to the center. The only difference is that this "paper" extends to $\infty$ in every direction.